# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'StringBuilder.AppendFormat' not found

Tags: c#

I've been following a tutorial by Derek Banas and so far it's been doing good however, I cannot use the StringBuilder correctly. It says that the AppendFormat is not found when it clearly must exist since it's auto-completing method.

Code

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Random Text");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("This is some more Random Text", 256);

            Console.WriteLine("Capacity : {0}",
                              sb.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("Capacity : {0}",
                              sb2.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("Length : {0}",
                              sb.Length);
            sb2.AppendLine("\nMore important text!");

            CultureInfo enUS =
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            string bestCust = "Bob Smith";
            sb2.AppendFormat(enUS, "Best Customer : {0}", bestCust);
            Console.WriteLine(sb2.ToString());

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you executing this?

Comment: Yes. As saravana asked, mention your .net version ;)

Comment: How do I figure it out in MonoDevelop? Kind of a noob at this ide, I'm also running Linux

Comment: Y'know what. Should probably install .net core ey

Comment: 1.0.4 is my .net core version I just downloaded

Comment: Ah, and I guess Linux can't get 4.6 :(

Comment: @Ethan Is available from 1.1 - 4.6 sorry. View all methods and their versions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906227(v=vs.110).aspx